# Footnote continues two pages after it breaks

Tags: footnotes

I use a `\footmisk` package (which is probably irrelevant in this case). I have a footnote which breaks on one page and continues two pges after, instead of the next page after the break.

Page 41 - beginning of the footnote:
[image]

Page 42 - horizontal line which separates footnotes from a main text:
[image]

Page 43 - continuation of the footnote:
[image]

I don't understand why it breaks in the first place, as it is not that long and it perfectly fits the first page.

Comment: You should raise the value of the TeX parameter `\interfootnotelinepenalty` (eg: `\interfootnotelinepenalty = 500`)

Comment: That's rather unusual behaviour, so you should make a complete, minimal example that demonstrates the issue and which can be used for debugging.

Comment: @F.Pantigny changing the parameter to \interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 helped, thx

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the problem with MWE is that if I change the text, tnis issue doesn't occur, so I only can provide exactly the same document I have, which is quite big.

Comment: I'm rather sure that you can shorten your document considerable without loosing the problem. E.g. all text after the problem is probably not needed. Also all chapters before the relevant chapter.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can't remove anything before the footnote, as the article doesn't have chapres, only sections (and they don't start right after the end of the previous section, not from a new page).

Comment: Go back three pages, and try to fake a starting point with \newpage\vspace*{some space}`

Comment: @David And you can use various amounts of `\lipsum` (large), `\lipsum[1-3]` (shorter), `\lipsum[1]` (even shorter), `\lipsum[2]`, `\lipsum[1][1-2]`, `\lipsum[1][1]`, etc., complemented by `whatever you want` to fill what precedes the problematic footnote precisely enough that it allows you to reproduce the problem. See the `lipsum` package.